# QML Box2D Install

Tags: qt, import, installation, qml, box2d

Following advice on a question I asked previously, I am trying to use Box2D with my QML app.

I have downloaded Box2D for QML here: https://github.com/qml-box2d/qml-box2d

I have followed the instructions :

- Extracted the files to my Import folder (Qt/5.4/android_armv7/imports/)
- Opened Box2D.pro in Qt and built it.
- The libBox2D.so file was created as per the instructions I was following.

I have tried using Box2D in my QML project.  First with my android app, then with a desktop app.

On each occasion I am getting an error:

> module "Box2D" is not installed

I'm stuck with this, can someone help me?

Comment: Did you run `make install`? Specifically, you should see some Box2D-related stuff in `Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml`, for example.

Comment: No... how do I run make install?

Comment: Go to the build directory of the project and type make install.

Comment: Tried that, but get the error 'make' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Then you need to run nmake.

Comment: nmake gives the same error...

Comment: That would mean that your development environment isn't correctly set up. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `make install` (`nmake install` on Windows) so that the Box2D files are installed to e.g. `Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml`, in your case. To use `nmake`, you need to have your development environment set up correctly. This is explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html), although that's specifically aimed at building Qt itself. If you're using MSVC, it is enough to open MSVC's developer command prompt and run `nmake` from there.